# how to create 2 arrays by running once on an array containing objects with the arrays matching the fields?

Tags: javascript

for example - lets say I have the array -

`const array = [{name: "first", val: 1}, {name: "second", val: 2}]`

I want to run once on that array and at the end of that run to have two arrays -

`const arrayOne = ["first", "second"];`
`const arrayTwo = [1,2];`

to get the first one is easy, but getting both at once?

I remember there was a way to do it but couldn't find it..

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const array = [{name: "first", val: 1}, {name: "second", val: 2}]

const keys = [];
const values = [];

array.forEach(item=>{
  keys.push(item.name);
  values.push(item.val);
})

console.log(keys, values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any looping logic will help

`Array.reduce` implementation will be like below

```js
const array = [{ name: "first", val: 1 }, { name: "second", val: 2 }];
const [arrayOne, arrayTwo] = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name, val } = curr;
  acc[0].push(name);
  acc[1].push(val);
  return acc;
}, [[], []]);
console.log(arrayOne, arrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to achieve this:

```js
const array = [{name: "first", val: 1}, {name: "second", val: 2}]

const result = array.reduce((res, item) => {
  res[0].push(item.name)
  res[1].push(item.val)
  return res
}, [[], []])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `extractArrays` is general-purpose and can be used in other cases as well.

```js
function extractArrays(arr) {
  const result = {};
  for (obj of arr) {
    for (key in obj) {
      result[key] = (result[key] || []).concat([obj[key]]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const array = [{name: "first", val: 1}, {name: "second", val: 2}];
const result = extractArrays(array);
const arrayOne = result.name;
const arrayTwo = result.val;

console.log(`arrayOne=${arrayOne}`);
console.log(`arrayTwo=${arrayTwo}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone!

but I think that the easiest, most readable code would be something like -

```
const itemArray = [], valArray = [];
data.map(({name, val})=> {
if(name) nameArray.push(name);
if(val) valArray.push(val);
})
```

because basically in 4 lines of code it's finished
thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Array.map function:

```
const array = [ { name: 'first', val: 1 }, { name: 'second', val: 2 } ]

let names = array.map(item => item.name)
let vals = array.map(item => item.val)

console.log(names)
console.log(vals)
```

The map function calls a callback function you provide on each element and constructs a new array from the results of that function.

If you are not familiar with arrow functions like:

```
item => item.name
```

... it is a short form for:

```
function (item) {
  return item.name
}
```

You could even do it in one line:

```
let [ names, vals ] = [ array.map(item => item.name), array.map(item => item.val) ]
```